# Is it possible to disable wrapping of inline HTML with <p> tags?

Tags: org-mode, html, css

If I have the following line in an `org-mode` file

```
@@html:<section>@@
```

If I export to `HTML`, it becomes:

```
<p>
<section><br>
</p>
```

This applies the `CSS` I have for my `<p` tags around the `<section>` tag, resulting in a lot of unwanted padding.

If I use the following:

```
#+begin_export html
<section>
#+end_export
```

I get the tag without the `<p>` tags, but that's three lines of text just for a single tag.

For background, I'm trying to see if I can get [tufte-css](https://edwardtufte.github.io/tufte-css/) to work with `org-mode`'s `HTML` export. The `CSS` requires headings to be wrapped in `<section>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like

```
#+HTML: <section>
```

does the trick.

It adds the `<section>` without wrapping it in `<p>` tags.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What trick does it do? Why/how does this answer the question?